# Update panel not working in Datalist control in asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, html, css, asp.net

Basically I have this situation

```
Page > Update Panel > User Control > Data list  > User Control (Within item template) > Update Panel
```

When I click on a button within the inner most update panel, I want the content of the update panel to update. This isn't happening. However, the click handler is being hit fine asynchronously. The update panel just doesn't want to update.

I've tried different permutations of this; i.e. having the button outside the panel and adding a trigger etc but I just cannot get it to update.

It appears that because the user control is within an item template of the parent list view it causes the update panel to not update for some reason..

Comment: It'll be easier to help if you post your markup and/or code.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :-)
Please look at [ask]
and how to create a [mcve]. This will help to get useful answers.